# Luks encrypted hard drive won't boot

Tags: boot, server, mount, encryption, luks

To start, I apologize if this question has been asked before.  I've never had this happen before and I have a hard time trying to diagnose my issue.

**The problem:** 
I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with a Luks Encrypted drive.  The hardware is a little on the dated side, but recently when I try to boot the server, I get this:

```
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad.  Falling back to internal scanning.
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "*GROUP NAME*" using metadata type lvm2
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad.  Falling back to internal scanning.
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "*GROUP NAME*" now active
cryptsetup: sda5_crypt set up successfully
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... Btrfs loaded
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root] fsck.ex4 -a -CO /dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root
/dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root: recovering journal
[   79.848109] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   79.849226] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT.
[   84.849226] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   84.849226] ata1: SRST failed (errno=16)
[   84.849226] ata1: soft resetting link

**REPEATS SEVERAL TIMES** 

fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to re-open /dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root

/dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root: *********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors ***********

fsck exited with status code 12
```

After the failed fsck, I get dumped into initramfs.

**What I tried:**
I tried looking up `fsck error code 12` and get a lot of random questions with different error codes that don't really solve my problem.

I also found a few articles running `fsck` on a live CD after decrypting and mounting the partition.  Usually the output I get is `fsck (2.27.1)` with no success/fail/error number, and the drive still won't boot.  I also tried to repair the superblock, but after it successfully repairs, I get the same drive output as above.

I'm a bit stumped as of now, not sure how to proceed or how else to troubleshoot this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try this but dont decrypt the partion boot into live dvd run #sudo udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda then #sudo fsck /dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root

Comment: @Ccunlimited I did that and it let me unlock, but when running fsck on /dev/mapper/*GROUP NAME*-root, I get the same short read error.  Trying to look around on fixing a short read error and found a tutorial on using e2fsck -f, but it gives me a short read error followed by "Could this be a zero-length partition?".  Not sure what next.